# Transfer ERC20 (usdt) token between two addresses using web3.py

Tags: solidity, erc-20, web3.py

Here is my code:

```
token_from = "0x0d0707963952f2fba59dd06f2b425ace40b492fe"
token_to = "0x763015f098cf18cfa28baf25653955f271fb63ff"
token_to_private_key = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000"
my_provider = Web3.IPCProvider("~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/docker/jsonrpc.ipc")
w3 = Web3(my_provider)
contractAddress = "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7"
token = w3.eth.contract(Web3.toChecksumAddress(contractAddress), abi=usdtABI)

transaction = {
    'from': token_from,
    'to': token_to,
    'nonce': w3.eth.getTransactionCount(Web3.toChecksumAddress(token_from)),
    'gas': 2000000,
    'gasPrice': 234567897654321,
    'data' : token.caller.transfer(Web3.toChecksumAddress(token_to), 10000000),
    'chainId': 1,
}

signed = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(transaction, token_to_private_key)
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
TypeError: Transaction had invalid fields: {'data': []}
```